# Past Perfect Continuous: should I use 'had' twice?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

Should I use 'had' twice in a Past Perfect Continuous sentence?

Which of two sentences is correct?

> ...you know nothing about it until you **had been smacked** on the back or **yelled** at.
>
> ...you know nothing about it until you **had been smacked** on the back or **had been yelled** at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to repeat *had*, following the conjunction, as it is implied. Given the the present tense (*know*) in the principle clause, I would revise it as follows:

...you know nothing about it until you have been smacked on the back or yelled at.

*Had* would be appropriate, if the primary clause had been in the past tense, to wit:

...he knew nothing about it until he had been smacked on the back or yelled at,